# College Scorecard Raw Data Question

Tags: collegescorecard

on the data download page, there is a file called "Most recent data 124 MB csv", Does anyone know what the time period is? 2014? 2015? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Different data elements measure different outcomes for different student cohorts at different times. In order to understand which data elements correspond to which measurement periods, please see the data cohort map which is also included in the downloadable ZIP file.